# What is the timeline of Hearts of Iron 4?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

Title says it all, really: does HoI4 has the same timeline of HoI3, or has it been modified?

Comment: may I ask why the downvote? I've searched the wiki, but it did not turn up anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The timeline of Hearts of Iron IV version 1.0, is from 1 January, 1936 – indefinite.

There is no technical end date at the moment, but content like researchable technologies are only featured up to 1948.

There is also a 14 August, 1939 starting date.

---

There are currently reports of players who have played to the 1960s and fought out "WW3" - i.e. subsequent High World Tension-triggered wars, for instance between the Allies and the Comintern, following the defeat of the Fascist faction in WW2.

Note that there have been reports that the very late-game can be very taxing on computer resources, as of version 1.0. This may make the extremely late-game impossible to carry out in practice.

Comment: @Federico: Added. Should mention that the 1939 starting date is basically supposed to emulate WW2 historical starting conditions, although historically the war is held to have started 1 September, 1939.

Answer (score 5):

You can start the game in either **1936** or **1939**.

You will be shown a score screen **after 1948** if there are currently **no wars involving 3 or more major nations**. You will then have the option to continue playing. (Achievements are still available if playing a 1936 game in Ironman mode.)

See [this forum post](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/1948-game-end-not-happend-second-time.952093/#post-21480711) for the exact definition.